# How can I update my Java AWT frame when an element on it changes?

Tags: java, awt, paintcomponent

I'm new to programming and I can't seem to sort this problem: how can I make the frame of my app change? It's a Minesweeper game. The program logic is good, events are working, but the frame itself isn't repainting itself... I did not have this kind of problem with applets.. how can I make this work?

```
public void paint(Graphics g) {
    Graphics2D g2=(Graphics2D)g;
    _Main.toPaint(g2);
}
public void update(Graphics g) {
    Graphics offgc;
    Image offScreen=null;
    Dimension d=size();

    offScreen=createImage(d.height, d.width);
    offgc=offScreen.getGraphics();

    offgc.setColor(getBackground());
    offgc.fillRect(0, 0, d.width, d.height);
    offgc.setColor(getForeground());

    paint(offgc);
    g.drawImage(offScreen,0,0,this);
}
```

Comment: 1) Why AWT rather than Swing?  See my answer on [Swing extras over AWT](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6255978/418556) for many good reasons to abandon using AWT components.  If you need to support older AWT based APIs, see [Mixing Heavyweight and Lightweight Components](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/mixing-components-433992.html). 2) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: I want to learn awt and swing too. Will look swing too.. but I put awt first. Thank you btw!

Comment: *"but I put awt first."*  That makes no sense.  In fact, when people go from AWT to Swing, they need to 'unlearn' what they knew about AWT components.  The *only* reason it actually makes sense to learn about AWT *components* is if you actually expect to be forced to code using AWT components in a job.  That is *extremely* unlikely to happen.

Comment: Thanks very much! I wanted to apply for a job and they're using AWT.. but maybe my information was incorrect.. I'll change to swing.. there are a lot more things for swing to learn from.. Thanks for the heads up!

Comment: *"they're using AWT"*  My *deepest* sympathies.

Answer (score 2):

Seems you draw your graphics wrong. For [custom paintings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) you need to use [`paintComponent(...)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#paintComponent%28java.awt.Graphics%29) method of `JComponent`, for example of `JPanel`, instead of `paint()` method and custom `update()`. For updating your component graphics just call `repaint()` method.

Here is simple example with drawing for you,try and examine that:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.Random;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;


public class Example extends JPanel{

    private Random rand = new Random();

    public static void main(String... s){
        JFrame f = new JFrame();
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        final Example example;
        f.add(example = new Example());

        JButton b = new JButton("repaint");
        b.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                example.repaint();
            }
        });
        f.add(b, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        f.setSize(200,200);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

    public Example(){
        setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        for(int i =0; i<10;i++){
            int nextInt = rand.nextInt(getHeight()-10);
            int nextInt2 = rand.nextInt(getWidth()-10);
            g.fillRect(nextInt2, nextInt, 10, 10);
        }
    }
}
```

Also read recommendations of Andrew Thompson.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `JFrame` class. Let's say your `JFrame` is called `frame`. Try `frame.pack()`, then `frame.repaint()`. The only problem with this is that I don't know how to make the `frame.repaint()` method invoke itself mid-Thread; it wants to wait until the Thread is terminated.